# Cancel SpeechRecognition if nothing captured

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am trying to develop and app that listens and speaks back to the user. I am trying to make it as handsfree as possible.

My issue is that if the user does not respond in time, the SpeechRecognition will timeout, and the user will need to press the button to start listening again.

*Is there a way for me to do a work around where if nothing is heard by the application, it can prompt to try again and restart the listener?

CODE:

```
//Function i call when a user input is required.
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    System.out.println("REQUEST CODE: " + requestCode);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            System.out.println("resultCode: " + resultCode);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                input = result.get(0).toLowerCase();
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

I also have code that will read text to the user, and then prompt for voice input after its finished.

Please let me know if i can provide more details or code. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make google speech handsfree without clicking the "mic button", you have to make your own class for the recognizer, i wrote the code in xamarin-android, so it's pretty similar on java :

```
Public class CustomRecognizer : Java.Lang.Object, IRecognitionListener, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
private SpeechRecognizer _speech;
private Intent _speechIntent;


public string Words;


public CustomRecognizer(Context _context)
{
    this._context = _context;
    Words = "";
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech, RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000); 
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
}

void startover()
{
    _speech.Destroy();
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
StartListening();
}
public void StartListening()
{
    _speech.StartListening(_speechIntent);
}

public void StopListening()
{
    _speech.StopListening();
}

public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
{
}

public void OnEndOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
{
    Words = error.ToString();
    startover();
}
```

**When the recognizer got timeout, it will call OnError Event**
. On my code, i put startover() to restart the recording.

Comment: This answer worked for me with minor changes. I am glad to be able to use this method over my previous, which was using a Servcie for the listener. Thank you!